# How to add ffmpeg in my python program in exe

Tags: python, ffmpeg, path, auto-py-to-exe, ffmpeg-python

I created a program that downloads videos from YouTube and in the last step I use the ffmpeg library to combine audio and video streams into one video file. Then I converted this program to exe using auto-py-to-exe. But the program works only on a PC on which ffmpeg is installed in a windows environment variable, that is, it is added to PATH. But how can I make the program work on any PC without adding ffmpeg to the PATH?

Here is the part of the program where ffmpeg is used:

```
video_stream = ffmpeg.input('video.mp4')

audio_stream = ffmpeg.input('audio.mp4')

ffmpeg.output(audio_stream, video_stream, "out.mp4", vcodec="copy", acodec="copy").run()
```

I tried to run the program when I wrote it and converted it to exe and it worked on my PC. But on another PC on which ffmpeg is not installed in windows PATH, the program did not work.